# Dependency issue with setuptools while using pip to install python package

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, pydotplus

I'm trying to install the package hana-ml (machine learning package from SAP Hana Database). I use pip with virtual environments to manage packages.

```
pip install hana-ml --proxy <my_companys_proxy>
```

It throws the following error:

```
Collecting hana-ml
  Downloading hana_ml-2.19.24013100-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (13 kB)
Collecting hdbcli>=2.18.22 (from hana-ml)
  Using cached hdbcli-2.19.21-cp36-abi3-win_amd64.whl.metadata (6.3 kB)
Collecting pydotplus (from hana-ml)
  Using cached pydotplus-2.0.2.tar.gz (278 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None))': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None))': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None))': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None))': /simple/setuptools/
      WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None))': /simple/setuptools/
      ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement setuptools>=40.8.0 (from versions: none)
      ERROR: No matching distribution found for setuptools>=40.8.0
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

When I check if setuptools is installed with

```
pip list
```

I get that:

```
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        23.3.2
setuptools 69.0.3
```

So it seems to be already installed and satisfying the requested requirement.

The issue happens when it tries to install a depency. Namly the package pydotplus (it tries to install the current version 2.0.2).

```
Collecting pydotplus (from hana-ml)
  Using cached pydotplus-2.0.2.tar.gz (278 kB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I tried the following things.

1. Directly trying to install pydotplus
2. Installing pydotplus in a different lower version
3. Installing within an existing virtual environment
4. Installing within a completely new virtual environment
5. Installing outside of virtual environments.
6. Everything above in different networks (homeoffice-network and office-network)

Nothing helped and nobody in my company had similar issues. Does anyone have a clue?

Comment: your error mesage shows up on google. "Someone on the internet"(tm) seems to have circumvented [that issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/12050) by explicitly adding an implicit dependency (that's what I understood at least, see [this PR](https://github.com/jaraco/pip-run/pull/74) and [its diff](https://github.com/jaraco/pip-run/pull/74/files) )

Comment: Can you show the complete error message please?

Comment: Sure, just done it.

Comment: `ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', ConnectionResetError(10054, 'Eine vorhandene Verbindung wurde vom Remotehost geschlossen', None, 10054, None))` is saying a proxy (or, more unlikely, the index server itself) is closing the connection. You'll need to fix that.

Comment: installing wheels solved the problem. also with the proxy
```pip install wheel --proxy <my_companys_proxy>```